# Amazon S3 use virtual host for signed url

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am currently creating a system using AWS S3, my client needs a signed URL for his system. however I am currently having troubles setting up the virtual host for the signed URL.

Before the following code runs `$source=http://media.example.com/object-key` and `$host=media.example.com`

```
    $host = get_option('dn-s3-host');
        if (strpos($host,'http://') === FALSE) $host = 'http://' . $host;
        if (strpos($source,get_option('dn-s3-host')) !== FALSE) {
            $s3Client = new Aws\S3\S3Client(array(
                'version' => 'latest',
                'region'  => get_option('dn-s3-region'),
                'endpoint' => $host,
                'use_path_style_endpoint' => true,
                'force_path_style' => true,
                'credentials' => array(
                    // 'region'  => get_option('dn-s3-region'),
                    'key'=>get_option('dn-s3-key'),
                    'secret'=>get_option('dn-s3-secret')
                    )
            ));
            $source = str_replace('http://','',$source);
            $source = ltrim(str_replace(get_option('dn-s3-host'),'',$source),'/');
            $cmd = $s3Client->getCommand('GetObject',array(
                    'Bucket'=>get_option('dn-s3-bucket'),
                    'Key'=>$source
                ));
            $request = $s3Client->createPresignedRequest($cmd,'+2 hours');
            $source = (string) $request->getUri();
        }
    }
```

When this code runs, I am receiving this error:

```
<Error>
    <Code>NoSuchKey</Code>
    <Message>The specified key does not exist.</Message>
    <Key>bucket/object-key</Key>
    <RequestId>363C44A299AA1E88</RequestId>
    <HostId>
     aCUab3+AD6396dJRMX8rCfYDl9EMjEBDn9somLQa3Ii6Bm6GoJGHT+f/qSZGprcR+3iG/hXC3EQ=
    </HostId>
</Error>
```

My virtual host `media.example.com` is a CNAME record pointing to bucket.s3.amazonaws.com

If I access `http://media.example.com/object-key` I get the file correctly. How do I set this virtual host for the signed URL?

Comment: At least one of `'use_path_style_endpoint' => true,` or
                `'force_path_style' => true,` seems to be incorrect, since "path style" refers to URLs that supply the bucket name as the first element of the path, and that's exactly what your error indicates is happening, here.  Seems like it might be the second one.

Comment: I disabled `force_path_style` and nothing changes. When I disable `use_path_style_endpoint` the signed URL is `bucket.media.example.com ` instead of just `media.example.com`

Comment: You may want/need to uncomment the `// 'endpoint' => $host,`.  It feels like you're using this library not entirely as intended.  What I mean by that is that even though what you are trying to accomplish is entirely valid, it may not be a deliberate part of this library's functionality, thus may require a seemingly-illogical approach in order to succeed.

Comment: apologies, question edited. In the original code the endpoint is not commented out.

Comment: What does `$source` contain, immediately after the line `$source = ltrim(str_replace(get_option('dn-s3-host'),'',$source),'/');`?  Log the value.  It should only contain the path, and not the bucket, and no leading slash.

Answer (score 0):

If your Signed URL is invalid you will get error like below,

```
<Error>
<Code>MissingKey</Code>
<Message>
Missing Key-Pair-Id query parameter or cookie value
</Message>
</Error>
```

The error indicates, that the object does not exist.

Based on the error message,

```
 <Key>bucket/object-key</Key>
```

Looks like you have bucket repeated twice in your URL.

Try to print the actual signed URL and check what it is the URL looks like, that will give an idea of what error you made there.

Hope it helps.

Comment: That example error is a CloudFront error.  No CloudFront is mentioned in the original question.

Comment: I tried to print the object key before sending it to getCommand, and I am not getting bucket/object-key